# CCDT File not created when using IBM MQExplorer

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to create the Client Channel Definition Table using IBM MQ Explorer 7.5.0.2. I have found several articles here which go through the steps of creating the options using the graphical UI in MQ Explorer but when I click 'Finish' nothing is created in the qmgrs folder. i.e. I run MQ Explorer as an Administrator and I have created a Channel definition and then a new Client Connection which I can see in the list of Client Connections but when I click on  OK in the dialogue with the options, nothing is created in the Qmgrs folder.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: The CCDT file, AMQCLCHL.TAB file is created under the qmgrs/<qm name>/@ipcc directory.Have you looked there?

Comment: Note that MQ 7.5 went out of support 2 years ago in April 2018, the 7.5.0.2 maintenance was released almost 7 years ago in July 2013.  MQ v 8.0 (which went out of support  on April 30 2020) and later support creating the CCDT with `runmqsc` directly using the `-n` flag and `runmqsc` is included with the MQ client packages.   There is even a redistrbutable client package for linux and windows that you can just extract with tar or zip to get `runmqsc`.  I would suggest you look into getting on a later supported and more secure version of the product.

Answer (score 0):

I found the files. The problem is that all the documentation I read says that the qmgrs directory is created in the application directory for MQ (where it was installed). This is not correct. It is created in the MQ data folder which can be different. Whoever first installed our MQ environment set this to a different location. Easy when you find the problem!

Thanks to everyone for their help.